# DRF SerializerMethodField: 'obj' argument vs. self.instance

Tags: django-rest-framework

**What is the difference between `self.instance` and the argument `obj` in a Django REST Framework's [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)?**

Per the documentation of SerializerMethodField it discusses the `obj` argument:

> The serializer method referred to by the method_name argument should accept a single argument (in addition to self), which is the object being serialized.

[image: Image of code from DRF documentation displaying the <code>obj</code> parameter]

and also per the documentation of [Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) it discusses `self.instance`:

> When passing an initial object or queryset to a serializer instance, the object will be made available as `.instance`. If no initial object is passed then the `.instance` attribute will be None.

Do they refer the same object then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `obj` parameter that is passed to your method is based on the `source` argument to your SerializerMethodField.

Generally the `source` argument is just `"*"` and, `"*"` indicates to the serializer to pass the instance to the method.  If instead you set `source="date_joined"` on your SerializerMethodField, then your `get_days_since_joined` might look like this instead:

```
def get_days_since_joined(self, date_joined):
    return (now() - date_joined).days
```